# Why isn't this SFML C++ code working ?

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
 #include "SplashScreen.h"
 #include "Game.h"


 void SplashScreen::Show(sf::RenderWindow & renderWindow)
 {
   sf::Image image;
   if(image.loadFromFile("images/SplashScreen.png") != true)
   {
     return;
   }

   sf::Sprite sprite(image);

   renderWindow.draw(sprite);
  renderWindow.display();

   sf::Event event;
   while(true)
   {
     while(renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
     {
      if(event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed 
        || event.type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed
         || event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed )
       {
         return;
      }
     }
 }
}
```

where it says "" sf::Sprite sprite(image); "" the image in the brackets is underlined and comes up with the error - no instance of constructor matches the argument list

Any help ?

Comment: And which one of [these](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) takes an `Image`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sf::Sprite` doesn't take a `sf::Image` as constructor but a `sf::Texture`.
Use a `sf::Texture` instead of a `sf::Image` and it should work.

So your code to initialize Sprite shoud be something like:

```
sf::Texture texture;
if(texture.loadFromFile("images/SplashScreen.png") != true)
{
    return;
}
sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
```

Comment: could you please expand. i mean ive changed it to texture and still get an error ? what should the code look like? thanks again for the quick response

Comment: its okay ive done it :) made a stupid mistake :)) thanks alot, it works :))

Comment: im going through a tutorial and its in SFML 1.6 so changing it to 2.0 gets a bit confusing sometimes and i forget what to change. thankyou :)